# Trying to send a token with web3.py, why is the receiver's balance not going up?

Tags: ether, web3.py

When I use web3.py to send some coins from account1 to account2, account2 does not see a balance increase.

```
from web3 import Web3 ,HTTPProvider, IPCProvider
from solc import compile_source


addr = 'http://127.0.0.1:8545'
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(addr))

source_code = ' contract token { mapping (address => uint) public coinBalanceOf; event CoinTransfer(address sender, address receiver, uint amount);  function token(uint supply) { coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] = supply; } function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool sufficient) { if (coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] < amount) return false; coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount; coinBalanceOf[receiver] += amount; CoinTransfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount); return true; } }'

web3.personal.unlockAccount('<insert account 1 here>','password!')


compile_sol = compile_source(source_code)
contract_address = '0xC7c1F1129726df4148B756c356Dc64cb27d763AC' #test-net 

Mycontract = web3.eth.contract(abi=compile_sol['<stdin>:token']['abi'], bytecode = compile_sol['<stdin>:token']['bin'],bytecode_runtime = compile_sol['<stdin>:token']['bin-runtime'])
my_contract = Mycontract(contract_address)

print my_contract.call().coinBalanceOf(Account1)
hashs = my_contract.transact({
    'from': web3.eth.coinbase,
    'to': '<insert account 2 here>',
    'value': 231,
    'gas': 702438
}).sendCoin('<insert account 2 here>', 231)

print web3.eth.getTransaction(hashs)
print "----------------------------------\n"
print web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hashs)
print  hashs+"\n"
print web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.coinbase)

print my_contract.call().coinBalanceOf('<insert account 2 here>')
```

Account2 doesn't have any tokens. What do I have wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending a token, do not set the `to` or `value` fields in the `transact()` method.

### Original Code

> ```
> hashs = my_contract.transact({
>     'from': web3.eth.coinbase,
>     'to': '<insert account 2 here>',
>     'value': 231,
>     'gas': 702438,
> }).sendCoin('<insert account 2 here>', 231)
> ```

### New Code

```
hashs = my_contract.transact({
    'from': web3.eth.coinbase,
    'gas': 702438,
}).sendCoin('<insert account 2 here>', 231)
```

Note that both of the removed values are specified in the contract method call `sendCoin()`.

### Why?

*The `to` key*

When you interact with a contract, you send a transaction to it. The receiving account is only mentioned in the call to the contract function.

This is an interesting point that many people don't understand at first: Account 2 does not have a record that it owns the new token. It must query the contract to discover its own token balance.

*The `value` key*

Value is always about transferring ether, denominated in wei. When you send the token, the only cost in ether will be the gas paid to run the contract.

### Other Issues?

This is a long enough example that there may be other bugs hiding in there. I am not sure I found all the problems. If there are more, feel free to comment on my answer and add more details to your question about what's going on.

Comment: Based on your line `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hashs)` I assume that you confirmed that the transaction got mined. Please confirm that it has when retesting with my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The answer perfect. I send my token to Account2. This answer save my  all day. 